# array_unique not working as expected in php

Tags: php, array-unique

Here is a problem.
i am exploding a list of character by new line in an array. and doing array unique on it. but it is not working as expected.
below is code:

```
$list = "test
ok
test
test
ok
ok
test";
$list_explode = explode("\n", $list); //exploding the characters of the list from the input
//displaying unique 

array_map('trim', $list_explode);
$result = array_unique($list_explode);
print_r($result);
```

The result is

`Array ( [0] => test [1] => ok [6] => test )`

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`. It will tell you the strings are different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` and you'll see there difference between the "test"s ([take a look at codepad](http://codepad.org/dqjVCUMu)).

your code contains `\r\n` as linebreaks and you're splittoing at `\n`, so `\r` is still there at all entrys except the last one.

you're already using `array_map` to prevent this but forgot to use the retun-value (it doesn't work by reference) in the latter code. change that line to:

```
$list_explode = array_map('trim', $list_explode);
```

after doing this, you'll get what you expect ([see at codepad again](http://codepad.org/ulZg9vAe)).

Answer (score 2):

You've failed to take into account that your string has a sequence of `\r\n` for the line break. In exploding you've only removed the `\n` portion so what your result actually looks like is:

```
Array ( [0] => test\r [1] => ok [6] => test )
```

However, the `\r` does not print as a visible character (even though the code sees it).

Answer (score 1):

You can split multiple lines of text in two main ways:

1. Use `$list_explode = array_map('rtrim', explode("\n", $list));`
2. Use `$list_explode = preg_split("/\r?\n/", $list);`